# How to get right number for multivalue element?

Tags: mysql

I have an overview of around 100 t-shirts on my site. I have the possibility to filter on the size of the shirt and filter on the store (content from different stores). Unfortunately I can't get it work correctly. The filter for sizes gives the right sizes and numbers, but the webshop filter doesn't give the right numbers when you filter on size. When I filter for example on 'L' AND 'XL' the number of shirts at store X is 150. That's because there are 90 t-shirts in size 'L' and 60 in size 'XL'. That's not correct off course because there are only 100 T-shirts in the shop.

When someone filters on L and XL, I want at store X the right number of shirts. So when the 60 XL shirts are also available in L, the number has to be 90 (60 L and XL and 30 only L).

Does anyone know how i can get the right number? Because the JOIN can give multiple rows (sizes) as a result, maybe I do a LIMIT 1 or something like that there?

My query at this moment (that gives 150 as number for store X):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(webshops.name) AS number, 
    webshops.name 
FROM products 
INNER JOIN webshops 
    ON  webshops.id = products.webshop_id 
INNER JOIN  product_details 
    ON  product_details.product_id = products.id 
INNER JOIN  details sizes 
    ON  sizes.id = product_details.detail_id 
WHERE   products.category_id = 1
    AND
    (
        sizes.url_name = 'L' 
        OR
        sizes.url_name = 'XL' 
    )
GROUP BY 
    webshops.name
```

Datamodel:
products (id, name, description, etc)
webshops (id, name, url, etc)
product_details (detail_id, product_id)

details (id, name, detail_type_id)
1 - S - 2
2 - M - 2
3 - L - 2
4 - XL - 2

Comment: Is this the query that is not working? Can you provide some sample date?

Comment: This query doesn't give the right number of results. It gives 150 in stead of 100.

I've added some data.

Comment: What are the counts of each of the tables, along with the counts of distinct ids?

Comment: 3 webshops, 100 products, 4 sizes

Comment: I think somewhere in the query has to be a LIMIT 1 for the sizes? Now it counts both sizes for the total number that the webshop offer, but per product it only has to count as 1.